# Passing int through command line Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to pass an int into my function through the command line but I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong.

```
import sys

def main():
    populationSize = sys.argv[1]
```

I'm assuming only one int is passed so that's why I'm using the [1] but when I try to run this program this is what comes out of my terminal:

```
$ ./gs1.py 2500
: Permission deniedn3
```

Comment: Use `argparse` for parsing. Your error is unrelated to python, you don't have the permissions right on the file.

Comment: @simonzack I used chmod u+x what other permissions do I need to have? I've never needed any more permissions than that. I saw documentation on argparse and I was a bit confused but I also saw it done the more familiar c style so that's what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

See that "n3" at the end? You have embedded CRs in your script. Pass it through `dos2unix`.

Comment: Thanks this worked and now I know what to do in the future if I encounter this again! I also tried googling this permission and I got nothing so I would have never found this solution.